# problem in using if statement error -> [: missing `]'

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( x=7; x <= 65; x+=2 )) 

do


    if [ $x!=57 && $x!=59 && $x!=29 && $x!=53 ]
    then
        cd charged_$x 
        cp -f ~aman/user_ana_normal_mode/Testforaman/user_ana.so .
        cd ..
    fi

done
```

can't figure out the problem , please help

Comment: You may find www.shellcheck.net useful

Answer (score 4):

```
[ $x!=57 && $x!=59 && $x!=29 && $x!=53 ]
```

`[` is a command, it obeys the same rules as, say `ls`. `&&` is a shell way of conditionally grouping commands. In `[ foo && bar ]`, the shell runs the command `[ foo`, and if it succeeds, it runs `bar ]`. The `[` command fails because it expects to see a `]` as its last argument, and so the second command does not run.

The special conditional syntax `[[ .. ]]` however does support `&&` within it, so you could use `[[ $x != 57 && $x != 59 && ... ]]`. Note that it still requires whitespace around the operators. Plain `$x!=57` would be a test to see if `$x!=57` is a nonempty string, which it always is, regardless of the value of `x`.

Or, put the closing `]` before the `&&`: `[ "$x" != 57 ] && [ "$x" != 59 ] && ...`

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't need whitespace aroung `&&`: `[[ $x != 57&&$x != 59 ]]` or `[ "$x" != 57 ]&&[ "$x" != 59 ]` work.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( x=7; x <= 65; x+=2 )) 
do
    if [ "$x" -ne 57 ] && [ "$x" -ne 59 ] && [ "$x" -ne 29 ] && [ "$x" -ne 53 ]; then
        cd charged_$x 
        cp -f ~aman/user_ana_normal_mode/Testforaman/user_ana.so .
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

- Its better to have separate braces for each condition.
- We should use `-ne` rather than `!=`, since we are comparing integers.

Answer (score 0):

you use too many conditions at same time  so  you need to change syntax for that .

```
if  [ $x!=57 ] && [ $x!=59 ] && [ $x!=29 ] && [ $x!=53 ]
```

this will work

Comment: Also note that `!=` is intended for strings, while numeric comparisons could/should use `-ne`.

Comment: by putting spaces around comparison operator != it worked fine.  thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two errors: The `!=` operator needs spaces around it, and the `&&` should be between individual `[ ... ]` tests.

Rather than using a lot of individual tests:

```
for (( x = 7; x <= 65; x += 2 )); do
    case $x in
        29|53|57|59) ;;
        *)
            cp -f ~aman/user_ana_normal_mode/Testforaman/user_ana.so "charged_$x"
    esac
done
```

I've also removed the half useless `cd`.